# asin() not working properly in Java

Tags: java, android

If I try to get the sin and sin-1 of 0.5 degree, I get virtually the same answer.
sin-1(0.5) should have been 30.

```
Log.d("XYZ", Math.sin(Math.toRadians(0.5)) +"___"+ Math.asin(Math.toRadians(0.5)));
```

Result: `0.008726535498373935___0.008726757025787037`

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your equation is wrong from scratch. sin(0.5) is what you got, and sin-1(0.5) is an angle with a sine value of 0.5, which would be 30 degrees, therefore, in radian, 0.5… rad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the part of your code i.e. `Math.asin(Math.toRadians(0.5))` is wrong....
***0.5*** is a numerical value you don't need to change it to Radians the correct one is.

```
Log.d("XYZ", Math.sin(Math.toRadians(0.5)) +"___"+ Math.toDegrees(Math.asin(0.5));
```

the function "Math.asin(0.5)" give value in radians so you need to convert it to degrees.
and it is not "sin-1 of 0.5 degrees" rather it is" sin-1 of 0.5" ..."degrees" must not come...

Comment: yeah @jyoon I am sorry I got it...just wait I am editing my code..

Comment: sin^-1 0.5 = 30 degrees = 0.5… rad you are wrong.